# Which is the best way to handle bear jwt token to secure Java Rest-API in Playframework 2.5?

Tags: java, jwt, openid-connect, playframework-2.5, keycloak

While building a single page application with [Angular2](https://angular.io/) with [keycloak sso](http://www.keycloak.org/), the Java Backend Rest Api need to be secured in Playframework 2.5.x.

Unfortunately, i can't find any tutorial for how to handle the keycloak jwt token in Playframework with Java **without session involved**.

Which is the best way to do this? I have considered to use [custom filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters) or [custom action](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition) to retrieve the jwt token from the "Authorization" header of every routed HTTP request.

Are there any appropriated libs, which can deal with sessionless jwt token  in Play Framework 2.5.x for Java?

I am looking for something very similar to [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) (a js implementation) for Play in java.

Comment: I've used [JWT-Scala](https://github.com/pauldijou/jwt-scala) with its Play extension with success, but that is Scala-only, and I suspect retrofitting it to a Play Java application would be extremely cumbersome, if not impossible. You could study the implementation though...

Comment: Thanks for the hint.